# Understanding the event dispatching threat and invokeLater() method

Tags: java, swing, events

I wanted to confirm my understanding. The Event Dispatching Threat is a single threat to manage all GUI events generated from the user interface. The events queue-up to be run on the EDT. invokeLater() let's swing put the event handler's action on the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html):

> Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event dispatch thread. Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are not "thread safe": invoking them from multiple threads risks [thread interference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html) or [memory consistency errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

[`invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) (asynchronous) and [`invokeAndWait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) (synchronous) are utility methods to update GUI elements from another thread. Both dispatch `Runnable`s on the EDT after all pending AWT events have been processed.